# How to redirect to the authentication login the jwt token in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working with spring on the Back side implementing spring security and jwt for security and React on my front side, to which it wants to redirect to the login when the token has expired or does not have a generated token, this is what I do in for validate.
Here I show you the part where I am doing the redirect function using function instead of class in react

```
export default function Dashboard() {


function validateToken(){
fetch(endpoint,request)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  if(data.error==="Unauthorized"){
    history.push("/")
  }else{
    setUserList(data);
  }  
})}
return (
<div>
  {validateToken}
</div>)
```

This way I do it if it works it redirects but before redirecting it renders a part of the page for thousands of seconds that if you pay attention to it, you see how it looks and disappears, that's why I come to ask you for help if there is any way to execute that function before render something.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a state loading. In the beginning of the above function, set loading's value to true. And after success value or error from API, set loading's value to false.

And according to value of loading, show the component render code.

```
const [laoding, setLoading] = useState(false);

function validateToken() {
 setLoading(true);
 fetch(endpoint,request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    setLoading(false);
    if(data.error==="Unauthorized"){
      history.push("/")
    }else{
      setUserList(data);
    }  
})}

return {
  <div>
    {!loading && <Component />}
  </div>
}
```

This will avoid the flickering effect.